# JNA dlls in buildpath

Tags: dll, jna, search-path

i use ghost4j in an java webapplication. This lib loads a dll through JNA. now i want to place the dlls in the classpath, because the working dir of this application changes when i run a test, run it on server with eclipse, or just run a main function for testing purposes.

How can i tell JNA to look in the classpath?

i thought on something like

```
class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()
```

but how can i add this programatical to the searchpath? i don't like to add VM arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNA will look in `jna.library.path` for native libraries, falling back to system defaults (usually the same as `java.library.path`) if nothing is found there.

```
System.setProperty("jna.library.path", "/whatever/path/you/want");
```

Comment: thanks i used this with combination of class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()